# How can I test an LCD with an RGB port?

Tags: signal, lcd, converter, rgb, test

I want to test this LCD. When I connect its power, the message "no signal" appears on the screen.  How can I send a simple signal to it for testing?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Yes, a VGA sinal.

Comment: @winny VGA needs one of two sync signals and has no differential colour lines.

Comment: @asdfex That's indeed peculiar. Sync-on-green does exist and so does differential RGB. Found this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194844/testing-triple-differential-driver-ad-8147

Comment: This question, like your previous question about the same display, requires information what kind of signals the display expects. You would need to provide display brand and model number, and a data sheet or some kind of manual how to make the display work. No one can guess what kind of signals the display takes in, all there is a random display with random connector and ambiguous labeling, not enough to know what kind of signals it needs to work.